# Как сделать сохранение двух селектов в куки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использовал такой код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $container = $('.content');
var $select = $('#news-view');

function handleSelectValue() {
    var selectedClass = $select.find(':selected').data('class');
    $container.toggleClass('column', selectedClass != 'line');
    $.cookie("selected", selectedClass);
}

var cookie = $.cookie("selected");
if (cookie) {
    $select.find('[data-class="' + cookie + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
}

handleSelectValue();

$select.on('change', handleSelectValue);
```

});

Но он отлично подходит только для одного селекта, а мне нужно, чтобы сохранялось 2 на следующую страницу. Помогите, пожалуйста, переделать скрипт, чтобы сохраняло два значения у двух селектов, а не у одного

Comment: вы выбираете только 1 селект с `id = news-view`, вам же нужно выбрать все те, которые вы хотите отслеживать

Comment: Если я добавлю двум селектам одинаковый класс, допустим, sel и укажу вместо var $select = $('#news-view'); , var $select = $('.sel'); , то он просто не будет подставлять значения